# Exclude characters from check_plain() in Drupal form

Tags: php, string, forms, drupal, sanitization

I have a text field in my Drupal form, which I need to sanitise before saving into the database. The field is for a custom name, and I expect some users may want to write for example "Andy's" or "John's home".

The problem is, that when I run the field value through the check_plain() function, the apostrophe gets converted into `&#039;` - which means `Andy's code` becomes `Andy&#039;s code`.

Can I somehow exclude the apostrophe from the `check_plain()` function, or otherwise deal with this problem? I have tried wrapping in the `format_string()` function, but it's not working:

```
$nickname = format_string(check_plain($form_state['values']['custom_name'], array('&#039;' => "'")));
```

Thanks.

Comment: The title of this question shoud have been "Exclude characters from check_plain() in Drupal form" and not format_string()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't exclude handling of some character in [check_plain()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7), because it's simply passes your text to php function [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) with **ENT_QUOTES** flag:

```
function check_plain($text) {
  return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

**ENT_QUOTES** means that htmlspecialchars() will convert both double and single quotes to HTML entities.

Instead of check_plain() you could use htmlspecialchars() with **ENT_COMPAT** (so it will leave single-quotes alone):

```
htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

but that can cause some security issues.

Another option is to write custom regular expression to properly sanitize your input.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for your help T-34! How worried should I be about the security issues you mention..?

Comment: Probably you will not have any problems if you use db_insert() or db_query() with placeholders to save this value to the database. So you can use `htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')` or look into strip_tags()

Answer (score 0):

I've been a bit worried about the security issue T-34 mentioned, so I've tried writing a work-around function which seems to be working OK. The function strips out the apostrophes, then runs check_plain() on each part, and pieces it back together again, re-inserting the apostrophes.

The function is:

```
function my_sanitize ($text) {
  $clean = '';
  $no_apostrophes = explode("'", $text);
  $length = count($no_apostrophes);
  if($length > 1){
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
      $clean .= CHECK_PLAIN($no_apostrophes[$i]);
      if($i < ($length-1)){
         $clean .= "'";  
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    $clean = CHECK_PLAIN($text);
  }  
  return $clean;
 }
```

And an example call is:
    $nickname = my_sanitize($nickname);